# Having an apps overview in XFCE like in GNOME

Tags: gnome, xfce, gnome-shell

I am configuring my ubuntu XFCE desktop, and I would like to know if there exist a good alternative to the **Activities** overview of GNOME desktop.

More generally, where can I find customization guides for XFCE?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Xfdashboard** is a Gnome Shell like dashboard for the XFCE desktop. You can install it using Software (search for xfdashboard). You can find [documentation](https://docs.xfce.org/apps/xfdashboard/start) about it from the xfce desktop team. This page includes links to information on how you can set it up and assign it to a hotkey.